# Creating a WebService to be mapped as a Network Drive

Tags: c#, filesystems, nfs, smb, cifs

Edit: How do I go about creating a web service that can be mapped as a network drive? Flickr, Google Drive and Skydrive all support this, I would like to make a webservice that can as well.

Comment: I suppose there's a reason you can't just copy the files to the file system somewhere? Maybe even synchronize between the file system and whatever your source for the data is? Whatever the reason is, you'd do well to _tell_ us the reason.

Comment: The files are stored in a database. This allows me to navigate them by way of a metadata tree. It also means that when files are (re-)written, they are stored as a duplicate for simple versioning. The database also synchronizes with other databases for redundancy.

Currently my only interface to this is via a web server and manually browsing/downloading/uploading the files through a website. The server is on my local network, if I could somehow expose that logic as an NFS service then it would make file usage transparent as I could map the network drive.

I appreciate you giving feedback!

Comment: Have done some more searching online, the end functionality I'm trying to achieve is something where I can "Map network drive" like I would for my Google Drive or SkyDrive. Something like this: http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57347395-285/how-to-map-your-skydrive-folder-in-windows-7/